# Dynamic Text Box Colour change

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to change the colour of a Textbox dinamically depending on what time it is. At the moment my Form only consists of the Textbox but when I run it the Form isn't even displayed even though it's running.
the current code looks somewhat like this:

```
             time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") 
             If time.Substring(0, 1) = 0 Then
                Textbox.BackColor = Color.Red
             Else
                Textbox.BackColor = Color.Black
             End If
```

Edit:

1. this is for WinForms
2. the code is run in the Sub Form_Load
3. Goal is to have the Textbox change Colour as time changes e.g. everytime the seconds display a "7" it turns red

Comment: Can you add to the question: 1. Is this for `WinForms` or `WPF`. 2. Where in your code is this run? (if this is only a small test project, please post all the code). 3. Can you be a bit more descriptive on how you expect this to work eg: as the time changes, the colour changes or when the user presses a button

Comment: is it maybe hidden by default?

Comment: @JackSparrow No when I comment out the If Clause everything is perfectly visible for some reason

Comment: Have you tried with hex values instead of color.red or color.black??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Goal is to have the Textbox change Colour as time changes e.g.
> everytime the seconds display a "7" it turns red

The Load() event only fires ONCE when the form loads.  You need something that can check the current time at a regular interval.

For that, use a TIMER control and handle the Tick() event:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tmr.Interval = 100
        tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick
        Textbox.BackColor = If((DateTime.Now.Second Mod 10) = 7, Color.Red, Color.Black)
    End Sub

End Class
```